# How to make the coordinates on image dynamic and responsive with respect to the device screen in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

**Following is the image of Game I am trying to build using flutter for android:**

[Male body with tags naming body parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhN2A.png)

**Following is the code I have written and right now it's hardcoded for the Google Pixel, for portrait mode**

```
    Map _decoded;
    List oldData=[];
      int i=0;
    
    class IdentifyGame extends StatefulWidget {
      Function onScore;
      Function onProgress;
      Function onEnd;
      int iteration;
      bool isRotated;
    
      IdentifyGame(
          {key,
          this.onScore,
          this.onProgress,
          this.onEnd,
          this.iteration,
          this.isRotated = false})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State createState() => new _IdentifyGameState();
    }
    
    class _IdentifyGameState extends State
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      double x1 = 0.0,
          y1 = 0.0,
          x2 = 0.0,
          y2 = 0.0,
          x3 = 0.0,
          y3 = 0.0,
          x4 = 0.0,
          y4 = 0.0,
          x5 = 0.0,
          y5 = 0.0,
          x6 = 0.0,
          y6 = 0.0,
      String paste1 = '',
          paste2 = '',
          paste3 = '',
          paste4 = '',
          paste5 = '',
          paste6 = '',
      AnimationController _imgController;
    
      Animation animateImage;
    
      Future _loadGameAsset() async {
        return await rootBundle.loadString("assets/imageCoordinatesInfoBody.json");
      }
    
      Future _loadGameInfo() async {
        String jsonGameInfo = await _loadGameAsset();
        print(jsonGameInfo);
        this.setState(() {
          _decoded = json.decode(jsonGameInfo);
        });
        print((_decoded["parts"] as List));
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        this._loadGameInfo();
        _imgController = new AnimationController(
            duration: new Duration(
              milliseconds: 800,
            ),
            vsync: this);
        animateImage =
            new CurvedAnimation(parent: _imgController, curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
        _imgController.forward();
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
            [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
      }
    
      _renderChoice1(String text, double X, double Y) {
        setState(() {
          paste1 = text;
          x1 = X;
          y1 = Y;
        });
      }
    
      _renderChoice2(String text, double X, double Y) {
        setState(() {
          paste2 = text;
          x2 = X;
          y2 = Y;
        });
      }
    
      _renderChoice3(String text, double X, double Y) {
        setState(() {
          paste3 = text;
          x3 = X;
          y3 = Y;
        });
      }
    
      _renderChoice4(String text, double X, double Y) {
        setState(() {
          paste4 = text;
          x4 = X;
          y4 = Y;
        });
      }
    
      _renderChoice5(String text, double X, double Y) {
        setState(() {
          paste5 = text;
          x5 = X;
          y5 = Y;
        });
      }
    
      _renderChoice6(String text, double X, double Y) {
        setState(() {
          paste6 = text;
          x6 = X;
          y6 = Y;
        });
      }
    
      
      Widget _builtButton(BuildContext context, double maxHeight, double maxWidth) {
        print((_decoded["parts"] as List).length);
        int j = 0;
        int r = ((_decoded["parts"] as List).length / 5 +
                ((((_decoded["parts"] as List).length % 5) == 0) ? 0 : 1))
            .toInt();
        print(r);
        return new ResponsiveGridView(
          rows: r,
          cols: 5,
          children: (_decoded["parts"] as List)
              .map((e) => _buildItems(j++, e, maxHeight, maxWidth))
              .toList(growable: false),
        );
      }
    
      List _buildPartsList() {
        List partsName = [];
        for (var i = 0; i (i),
          part: part,
        );
      }
    
      _onDragStart(BuildContext context, DragStartDetails start) {
        print(start.globalPosition.toString());
      }
    
      _onDragUpdate(BuildContext context, DragUpdateDetails update) {
        print(update.globalPosition.toString());
      }
    
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _imgController.dispose();
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([]);
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print(_buildPartsList());
        Size media = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        double _height = media.height;
        double _width = media.width;
        print("height of screen from media is $_height ");
        print("width of screen from media is $_width");
        return new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
          return new Scaffold(
            body: new Flex(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              children: [
                new GestureDetector(
                  onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails start) =>
                      _onDragStart(context, start),
                  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails update) =>
                      _onDragUpdate(context, update),
                  onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails start) =>
                      _onDragStart(context, start),
                  onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails update) =>
                      _onDragUpdate(context, update),
                  child: new Container(
                      height: (constraint.maxHeight) * 3 / 4,
                      width: constraint.maxWidth,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                      ),
                      child: new Stack(
                        fit: StackFit.passthrough,
                        children: [
                          new ScaleTransition(
                            scale: animateImage,
                            child: new Image(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/' + _decoded["id"]),
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                          new RepaintBoundary(
                            child: new CustomPaint(
                              painter: new Stickers(
                                  text: paste1,
                                  x: x1,
                                  y: y1,
                                  height: _height,
                                  width: _width),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new RepaintBoundary(
                            child: new CustomPaint(
                              painter: new Stickers(
                                  text: paste2,
                                  x: x2,
                                  y: y2,
                                  height: _height,
                                  width: _width),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new RepaintBoundary(
                            child: new CustomPaint(
                              painter: new Stickers(
                                  text: paste3,
                                  x: x3,
                                  y: y3,
                                  height: _height,
                                  width: _width),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new RepaintBoundary(
                            child: new CustomPaint(
                              painter: new Stickers(
                                  text: paste4,
                                  x: x4,
                                  y: y4,
                                  height: _height,
                                  width: _width),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new RepaintBoundary(
                            child: new CustomPaint(
                              painter: new Stickers(
                                  text: paste5,
                                  x: x5,
                                  y: y5,
                                  height: _height,
                                  width: _width),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new RepaintBoundary(
                            child: new CustomPaint(
                              painter: new Stickers(
                                  text: paste6,
                                  x: x6,
                                  y: y6,
                                  height: _height,
                                  width: _width),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
                new Container(
                    height: (constraint.maxHeight) / 4,
                    width: constraint.maxWidth,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor),
                    child: _builtButton(
                        context, constraint.maxHeight, constraint.maxWidth)),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      }
    }
    
    class DragBox extends StatefulWidget {
      var part;
      double maxHeight;
      double maxWidth;
      Function render1;
      Function render2;
      Function render3;
      Function render4;
      Function render5;
      Function render6;
      Function onScore;
      Function onEnd;
    
      DragBox(
          {this.onEnd,
          this.onScore,
          this.maxHeight,
          this.maxWidth,
          Key key,
          this.part,
          this.render1,
          this.render2,
          this.render3,
          this.render4,
          this.render5,
          this.render6,})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      DragBoxState createState() => new DragBoxState();
    }
    
    class DragBoxState extends State with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      AnimationController controller, shakeController;
      Animation animation, shakeAnimation, noanimation;
    
      // Color draggableColor;
      // String draggableText;
      
      
      var part;
      int _flag = 0;
      double maxHeight;
      double maxWidth;
      Function render1;
      Function render2;
      Function render3;
      Function render4;
      Function render5;
      Function render6;
    
      static List _buildPartsList() {
        List partsName = [];
        for (var i = 0; i  data = _buildPartsList();
    
      _onDragStart(BuildContext context, DragStartDetails start) {
        RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
        var local = getBox.globalToLocal(start.globalPosition);
        print(local.dx.toString() + "|" + local.dy.toString());
      }
    
      _onDragUpdate(BuildContext context, DragUpdateDetails update) {
        RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
        var local = getBox.globalToLocal(update.globalPosition);
        print(local.dx.toString() + "|" + local.dy.toString());
      }
    
      void toAnimateFunction() {
        animation.addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
          if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
            controller.reverse();
          } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
            controller.forward();
          }
        });
        controller.forward();
      }
    
      void toAnimateButton() {
        shakeController.forward();
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        shakeController = new AnimationController(
            duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 800), vsync: this);
        controller = new AnimationController(
            duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 80), vsync: this);
        animation = new Tween(begin: -3.0, end: 3.0).animate(controller);
    
        animation.addListener(() {
          setState(() {});
        });
        shakeAnimation =
            new CurvedAnimation(parent: shakeController, curve: Curves.easeOut);
        noanimation = new Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.0).animate(shakeController);
    
        part = widget.part;
        maxHeight = widget.maxHeight;
        maxWidth = widget.maxWidth;
        render1 = widget.render1;
        render2 = widget.render2;
        render3 = widget.render3;
        render4 = widget.render4;
        render5 = widget.render5;
        render6 = widget.render6;
    
        toAnimateButton();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        controller.dispose();
        shakeController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size media = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        double _height = media.height;
        double _width = media.width;
    
        return new ScaleTransition(
          scale: shakeAnimation,
          child: new GestureDetector(
            onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails start) =>
                _onDragStart(context, start),
            onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails update) =>
                _onDragUpdate(context, update),
            onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails start) =>
                _onDragStart(context, start),
            onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails update) =>
                _onDragUpdate(context, update),
            child: new Draggable(
              data: part["name"],
              child: new AnimatedDrag(
                  animation: (_flag == 0) ? noanimation : animation,
                  draggableColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                  draggableText: part["name"]),
              feedback: new AnimatedFeedback(
                  animation: animation,
                  draggableColor: Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
                  draggableText: part["name"]),
              onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
                double hRatio = ((3 * maxHeight) / (4 * part["data"]["height"]));
                double wRatio = (maxWidth / part["data"]["width"]);
             
                
                if (part["name"] == "face" &&
                    (offset.dx > 360.0 && offset.dx  140.0 && offset.dy  336.0 && offset.dx  250.0 && offset.dy  260.0 && offset.dx  300.0 && offset.dy  430.0 && offset.dx  300.0 && offset.dy  392.0 && offset.dx  620.0 && offset.dy  220.0 && offset.dx  620.0 && offset.dy  animation,
          this.draggableColor,
          this.draggableText})
          : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
    
      final Color draggableColor;
      final String draggableText;
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size media = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        double _height = media.height;
        double _width = media.width;
        final Animation animation = listenable;
        return new Container(
          // width: _width * 0.15,
          // height: _height * 0.06,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(
              (_width > _height) ? _width * 0.01 : _width * 0.015),
          color: draggableColor.withOpacity(0.5),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(
              draggableText,
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontSize: (_width > _height) ? _width * 0.015 : _width * 0.03,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class AnimatedDrag extends AnimatedWidget {
      AnimatedDrag(
          {Key key,
          Animation animation,
          this.draggableColor,
          this.draggableText})
          : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
    
      final Color draggableColor;
      final String draggableText;
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size media = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        double _height = media.height;
        double _width = media.width;
        final Animation animation = listenable;
        double translateX = animation.value;
        print("value: $translateX");
        return new Transform(
          transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(translateX, 0.0, 0.0),
          child: new Container(
            // width: _width * 0.15,
            // height: _height * 0.06,
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(
                (_width > _height) ? _width * 0.01 : _width * 0.015),
            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: (_width > _height) ? _width * 0.005 : _width * 0.005,
              horizontal: (_width > _height) ? _width * 0.005 : _width * 0.005,
            ),
            color: draggableColor,
            child: new Center(
              child: new Text(
                draggableText,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: (_width > _height) ? _width * 0.015 : _width * 0.03,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Stickers extends CustomPainter {
      Stickers({this.text, this.x, this.y, this.height, this.width});
      final String text;
      final double x;
      final double y;
      final double width;
      final double height;
    
      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
            text: text,
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: (width > height) ? width * 0.015 : width * 0.03,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
        TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
            text: span,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
        tp.layout();
        tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(x, y));
        //canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();
        // canvas.saveLayer(rect, new Paint());
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(Stickers oldDelegate) {
        // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
        if (oldDelegate.text != text) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

I am new to flutter and building a game for dragging and dropping the tag with the name of a body part on it to the correct location on the shown image, images will come from the database and it will change after successful completion and submission. Now here I am struggling with making it responsive for every image that will get loaded from the database. Right now it's hardcoded for the shown image. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!